# Facing authentication error while fetching token for GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-virtual-device

I am trying to implement a basic client to receive GCM notifications based on the tutorial in https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start.

When running the application I am seeing the below error in the logs:

11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService: Failed to complete token refresh
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService: java.io.IOException: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:55)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-05 15:35:13.912 10201-10230/com.example.pandes4.sampleproject D/RegIntentService:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

[image: The error screenshot in the emulator is attached.]

Could anyone help out please.

Comment: I tried printing the sender ID which is received by this code: String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
It seems to be correct, as in its the same sender id which I got when I created the project.

Comment: are you using a real device or emulator? If so be sure that you are using one running the Google APIs?

Comment: I am using the emulator with Google API's.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that may be blocking the request to getToken?

Comment: Ok..that maybe the case since I am working in my office network, I'l try accessing the same from outside this network and update here

Comment: So it works when I am running the debug-apk after connecting my handset. I guess it was the firewall issue only. The only confusion is that a lot of people in my office do use GCM on emulators itself. Thanks Arthur for the assistance.

Comment: Hey @Sid, do you got some solution to run gcm within network? ie. some proxy setting or getting specific url out of firewall?

Comment: @malavshah: No couldnt find any solution for the emulator. On a physical device, I could get this working.